# Google sheets Regex extractreplace with split?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to separate that is in one cell, into different columns, and I have managed to do in two different cells, and wondering if it's possible to to in one step only:

List on C3:

["apples","oranges","avocados"]

I am able to split them, and remove [], but the "" still remain there:

```
=SPLIT(C3;"1234567890`-=[]\;',./!@#$%^&*()")
```

Result

D4                 E4              E5

"apples"    "oranges"   "avocados"

In order to remove the "", I could only find this, but has to be on a different cell and applied to all new cells:

`=REGEXREPLACE(D4;"[^[:alnum:]]"; "")` - Then copied to the next cells

Result (expected, but in two step, and having to expand the formula to all cells)

D5      E5      E6

apples  oranges avocados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=split(C3;"[],""")
```

Comment: I feel so dumb. I believe I tried adding the " , but it didn't work. Probably I did something wrong. Thanks a lot :)